# Cheating KNOX by cracking stock ROM certificate

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, rom, samsung-knox

I had some thoughts about KNOX and the fact that flashing stock ROM doesn't trip my KNOX flag. I did some research about the topic and I learned that KNOX checks ROM file's certificate or something like that. The files within a zip archive have .md5 file extension. Knowing a fact that MD5 is flawed hashing function which is considered broken so I can theoretically crack the password which it used to create md5 file checksum. Having this password I can sign a custom ROM with it and KNOX should be bypassed successfully. Are my thoughts correct and it's feasible or I misunderstanded something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it was that simple it would have been broken long back. Knox is almost fool proof and prevents any such attempts

> Samsung KNOX addresses security using a comprehensive, hardware-rooted trusted 
>   environment:
>
> • Hardware Root of Trust
>
> • Secure Boot and Trusted Boot
>
> • Security Enhancements for Android (SE for Android)
>
> • TrustZone-based Integrity Measurement Architecture (TIMA)
>
> • TrustZone-based Security Services

[Source: White paper on Knox by Samsung](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.samsung.com/ar/business-images/insights/2015/An_Overview_of_the_Samsung_KNOX_Platform_V1.11-0-0.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiU6siVm9nZAhXHso8KHYp6AXoQFjAHegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw1apDJMYZ-CM2ANeX2Khw26)

You can see the technical details but to summarise *any* changes made trigger a *fuse* that would flag tampering

> (Fuse is)...one-time 
>   programmable memory area (colloquially called a fuse) is written to indicate suspected 
>   tampering.

Next, *hardware root of trust* is specific to each device and that  verification would fail

Even flashing an older version of  stock ROM would trigger the fuse

> Rollback prevention fuses are hardware fuses that encode the minimum acceptable version of Samsung-approved executables. These fuses are set at manufacture time in the Samsung factory. Because old images may contain known vulnerabilities that can be exploited, this feature prevents approved-but-old versions of boot executables, from being loaded.

To summarise, you would see that it won't work

Comment: So there's no way to cheat KNOX? Any exploits, vulnerabilities?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.